# ggplot2: change the color of error bars w/o losing customized dodge parameters

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to change the color of my error bars to different colors without changing the position of the points on my graph.

Here is a bit of my data:

```
df <- structure(
  list(
    yrmonth = structure(
      c(
        1483228800,
        1483228800,
        1483228800,
        1485907200,
        1485907200,
        1485907200,
        1488326400,
        1488326400,
        1488326400,
        1491004800,
        1491004800,
        1491004800
      ),
      class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"),
      tzone = "UTC"
    ),
    index = structure(
      c(1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 5L),
      .Label = c("N-S", "N-S", "E-W", "E-W", "OS"),
      class = "factor"
    ),
    N = c(2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1),
    GDDLettuce = c(129, 141, 27, 150.5, 209, 87, 247.5,
                   243, 188, 223, 226.5, 170),
    sd = c(
      1.4142135623731,
      4.24264068711928,
      NA,
      4.94974746830583,
      65.0538238691624,
      NA,
      12.0208152801713,
      8.48528137423857,
      NA,
      5.65685424949238,
      0.707106781186548,
      NA
    ),
    se = c(1, 3, NA, 3.5, 46, NA, 8.5, 6, NA, 4, 0.5, NA),
    ci = c(
      12.7062047361747,
      38.1186142085241,
      NA,
      44.4717165766114,
      584.485417864036,
      NA,
      108.002740257485,
      76.2372284170481,
      NA,
      50.8248189446988,
      6.35310236808735,
      NA
    )
  ),
  .Names = c("yrmonth", "index", "N", "data", "sd", "se", "ci"),
  row.names = 31:42,
  class = "data.frame"
)
```

I have my graph set up exactly the way I want it with error bars in the right locations:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=yrmonth,y=data,colour=factor(index))) + 
  geom_line(size=1, position = position_dodge(width = -300000)) + ylim(min(df$data), max(df$data)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=data-se, ymax=data+se), width = 1000000, size = .5, 
                position = position_dodge(width = -300000))
```

When I add one color, the color of the bars change, but it removes all the width and dodge parameters that I put in:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=yrmonth,y=data,colour=factor(index))) + 
  geom_line(size=1, position = position_dodge(width = -300000)) + ylim(min(df$data), max(df$data)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=data-se, ymax=data+se), colour = "black", width = 1000000, size = .5, 
                position = position_dodge(width = -300000))
```

I would like the E-W error bars to be a dark green and the N-S error bars to be a dark red. I would like the lines themselves to stay the same color. Most importantly I want the error bars to stay in there same locations. For some reason, every time I change the color the position of my error bars and lines changes.

Comment: Your example produces an error: `Error in 'levels<-'('*tmp*', value = if (nl == nL) as.character(labels) else paste0(labels,  : 
  factor level [2] is duplicated`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick and easy solution would be

```
require(dplyr)
ggplot(df %>% mutate(errorColors = ifelse(index=="N-S","darkred",ifelse(index=="E-W","darkgreen",NA))), aes(x=yrmonth,y=data)) + 
    geom_line(aes(group=index,color=index),size=1, position = position_dodge(width = -300000)) + ylim(min(df$data), max(df$data)) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=data-se, ymax=data+se,color=errorColors), width = 1000000, size = .5, 
                  position = position_dodge(width = -300000))+scale_color_manual(breaks=c("E-W","N-S","OS"),values=c("darkgreen","darkred","green","red","blue"))
```

Comment: Thanks. Thats what I needed color wise, but it messes with the dodging and the error bars no longer line up with the points. I can't figure out why changing the color would effect the dodging.

Comment: adding `group = index` to `ggplot()` solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

try add one more layer `scale_color_manual` in your first plot code like this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=yrmonth,y=data,colour=factor(index))) + 
  geom_line(size=1, position = position_dodge(width = -300000)) + ylim(min(df$data), max(df$data)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=data-se, ymax=data+se), width = 1000000, size = .5, 
            position = position_dodge(width = -300000))+
  scale_color_manual(values = c('darkblue', 'darkgreen', 'darkred'))
```